# DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, ruby-on-rails-5

I am geeting below error:
DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error.

I added create.js.erb file recently to update post in browser without reload. Does that mean, data is getting saved in js format. because when i try to 
open micropost/show link, its working fine- data is getting loaded. but when i try to open micropost/index link, i get above error.

Before adding create.js.erb file, i had data saved in DB in HTML format.

controller:

```
def create
@user = current_user
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
if @micropost.save
  respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  end
end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#micropost_refresh').prepend("<%= j render @micropost %>");
$('#micropost_count h3').replaceWith("<h3>Microposts (<%=@user.microposts.count %>)</h3> ");
```

show.html.erb

```
<section class="micropost_form">
<%=form_for((Micropost.new), :remote => true, :id =>'new_micropost') do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>   
</section>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div id="micropost_count">
  <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
  <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3></div>
  <div id="micropost_refresh">
  <ol class="microposts">
  <% @user.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  <li>   <%= render 'microposts/micropost', micropost: micropost %></li> 
  <% end %>
  </ol></div><% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

controller:

```
 def index
 @microposts = Micropost.all
  respond_to do |format|
      request.format = "html"
      format.html
     end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="card-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered display" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" data-source="<%= microposts_path(current_user, format: "json") %>">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <% if current_user.admin? %>
        <th>User</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
        <% end %>
        <th>Event Category</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= micropost.created_at %></td>
      <% if current_user.admin? %>
      <td><%= micropost.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= micropost.user.phone_number %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= micropost.events.pluck(:category_id).first %></td>
      <td class="content"><%= micropost.content %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When i post a message, it should automatically update in the page without reloading which it does. But same data is not getting loaded into datatable.
Please someone help me with this.

Comment: In the error message there is a link. Click it and it will tell you about the problem, and the format you need to return your data in for Datatables to work with it properly

Comment: I got this code in the link.
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';

This should go into which file. Should i add any exception?